# How to return the value of SweetAlert2 input?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

This is the current code I have

```js
function getInput() {
  Swal.fire({
    input: "text",
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result) {
      return(result.value);
  });
}

function main() {
  if (condition) {
    const test = getInput();
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
}
```

I know this isn't correct because it returns undefined. I've tried looking for a bunch of solutions but I always get undefined or the promise itself returned, have no idea how I'm supposed to get the value.

What I want to do is somehow return the value of the SweetAlert2 input so that I can use it in other functions.

### Edit

I think I got mostly what I had wanted to do. Instead of putting the `then` handler in `getInput()`, I put it on `test`, so then I could put the rest of my code in the handler.

```js
function getInput() {
  return Swal.fire({
    input: "text",
  })
}

function main() {
  if (condition) {
    const test = getInput();
    test.then((result) => {
      if (result) {
        // do stuff
      }
    });
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideal use case to use a [**`callback`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) as your program is not certain when the value will be returned.

In `then` handler, callback function will be invoked and `input` will be passed as an argument.

```js
function getInput(cb) {
  Swal.fire({
    input: "text",
  }).then((result) => {
      if (result) {
        return cb(result.value);
      });
  }
}

function main(input) {
  console.log(input);
}

getInput(main)
```

Comment: I see, I can probably work my code around to work with this, but it isn't really ideal, since my `main()` function has an if condition that controls whether the SweetAlert2 is used. Using callback would require me to put the condition outside, which basically removes the purpose of the `main()` function.
I edited my code example to demonstrate what I mean.

Comment: Are you saying `main` and `getInput` are independent functions? @Cosmos

Comment: If that is the case, I would store value of `input` in global variable and rest of the code will be based on the `global` variable.